# What is the easiest way to create a survey with Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I took a look at surveyor and smerf but it looks like smerf is a plugin that is only used with Rails2, and surveyor did not work with my Rails3 install so I'm wondering if you guys have any other recommendations that would make the job easier?

Comment: Great answers so far. I'm basically asking if there is a gem that handles storing and creating the forms in the db on our end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find this very useful. It's on nested forms but does pretty much what you want :

http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2

Answer (score 2):

How about doing something completely different? wufoo has a great app for doing surveys, generate reports etc. and you can embed the survey forms in your app. I reckon you could be done in 30 minutes for now. So unless you explicitly need the data in your own database...

(Disclaimer: I'm not affiliated in any way with wufoo - I just think it's a great service and the basic account is free.)